# Alternative of BYROW for LAMBDA results of array

Tags: arrays, excel, function, excel-formula, office365

I'd like to vstack multiple arrays which  are results from rather complex calculations. Please see demo below:

```
|NameList|
----------
|A       |
|B       |
|C       |
|...     |
```

Arrays of FILTERed data with variables from NameList:

```
Array A  Array B  Array C  ...
|G2|Br|  |Jj|ua|  |Ac|Po|
-------  -------
|L7|S#|  |e0|ww|
         -------
         |Dx|on|
```

What I was trying to achieve is to get all arrays with BYROW and vstack them together (I assume VSTACK is not really necessary) but with formula below I only get an error:

```
=BYROW(NameList,LAMBDA(arr,FILTER(...)))
```

This simpler example replicate the error:

```
=BYROW(NameList,(LAMBDA(arr,EXPAND(arr,2,2,"")))
```

I just learned that BYROW only works when LAMBDA returns a single value. But I have no idea how to achieve what I want with other function.

Please help.

Comment: Try `=DROP(REDUCE("",A2:A11,LAMBDA(rr,r,VSTACK(rr,EXPAND(r,2,2,"")))),1)`.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Given name list and array don't seem to have any match at all. But as VBasic2008 mentioned, REDUCE makes it possible to create a 2D spill range from a 1D range.

Comment: Really appreciate both of your help. I made it with VBasic2008's solution.

Comment: Using the `EXPAND` example was a great idea to replicate your issue.

Comment: Respect to @VBasic2008 for understanding the goal.
Still curious of what you finally made from it since VBasics comment is an interpretation of what you may mean from one o the formulas posted, but the examples show something completely different. Or was it simply the intention to spill a blank value in between each row? Then why do you need a blank column to the right of that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to VBasic2008's comment, I achieved this with the following lambda which has the same signature as BYROW:

```
LAMBDA(arr,fn,LET(indices,SEQUENCE(ROWS(arr)),DROP(REDUCE("%DROPPED_VALUE%",indices,LAMBDA(output,indx,VSTACK(output,fn(INDEX(arr,indx,))))),1,0)))
```

It works by generating an index for each row in the array `arr` with SEQUENCE, e.g.

```
1
2
3
...
```

Then within the `DROP ... REDUCE ... VSTACK` trick for operating on each index, it uses those indices to index into the original array `arr`, and calls the provided function `fn` on it.

The BYCOL equivalent:

```
LAMBDA(arr,fn,LET(indices,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(arr)),DROP(REDUCE("%DROPPED_VALUE%",indices,LAMBDA(output,indx,HSTACK(output,fn(INDEX(arr,,indx))))),0,1)))
```

You use these like `BETTER_BYROW(arr, fn)` e.g.

```
=BETTER_BYROW(A1:A11, LAMBDA(r, TEXT_SPLIT(r, " ")))
```